# Ruby on rails form data not not getting saved

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

So i am getting trouble in saving form data,.Any help will b appreciable
form is submitted without getting any error, but in database, nothing is stored
i am new on rails

> users_controller

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user= User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:User])
    if @user.save
        flash[:notice]= "you signed up successfully"
        flash[:color]= "valid"
    else
        flash[:notice]= "failed"
        flash[:color]="invalid"
    end
    render "new"
  end
end
```

> new.html.erb

```
<% page_title="Signup" %>
<div class="Sign_Form">
    <h1>Sign up</h1>
    <%= form_for(:user, :url => {:controller => 'users', :action => 'create'}) do |f| %>
    <p> Username:</br> <%= f.text_field :username %> </p>
    <p> Email:</br> <%= f.text_field :email %> </p>
    <p> Password:</br> <%= f.password_field :password %></p>
    <p> Password Confirmation:</br> <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %> </p>
    <%= f.submit :Signup %>
  <% end %>
  <% if @user.errors.any? %>
    <ul class="Signup_Errors">
    <% for message_error in @user.errors.full_messages %>
      <li>* <%= message_error %></li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

> in app/models/user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessor :password
  EMAIL_REGEX = /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i
  validates :username, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true, :length => { :in => 3..20 }
  validates :email, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true #:format => EMAIL_REGEX
  validates :password, :presence =>true #:confirmation => true #password_confirmation attr
  validates_length_of :password, :in => 6..20, :on => :create
end
```

Comment: If you are using Rails 4 you need to use [strong parameters](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters).

Comment: and how to get that? @max

Comment: Google for 'rails guide strong parameters'

Comment: The link is already right there in my comment :)

Answer (score 2):

In users_controller, create method, you are using

```
@user = User.new(params[:User])
```

replace it with following code, hope it will work fine.

```
@user = User.new(params[:user])
```

And,also use strong params if you are using rails 4. Like follwoing.

```
def create
  @user = User.new(user_params)
  if @user.save
    flash[:notice]= "you signed up successfully"
    flash[:color]= "valid"
  else
    flash[:notice]= "failed"
    flash[:color]="invalid"
  end
  render "new"
end

private  
  def user_params  
    params.require(:user).permit(:username, :account, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)    
  end
```

If, it still not works, then, please display your log.

Comment: To be clear, it looks like you are calling `params[:User]` with an upper case letter U.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Rails 4 you need to use [strong parameters](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters) to whitelist the parameters you want to assign to your models.

This became non-optional in Rails 4 to prevent mass-assignment vulnerabilities where a malicious user can assign any property to a model after Egor Homakovs much publicised Github attack.

Also note that Ruby is case sensitive. This applies to hash keys as well:

```
irb(main):003:0> hash = { a: 1 }
=> {:a=>1}
irb(main):004:0> hash[:A]
=> nil
```

Which is why why you do `User.new(params[:User])` you are actually doing `User.new(nil)`

This is a corrected version of your controller

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user= User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:User])
    if @user.save
      flash[:notice]= "you signed up successfully"
      flash[:color]= "valid"
      # You should redirect instead of rendering the form again
      redirect_to @user # or redirect_to root_path
    else
      flash[:notice]= "failed"
      flash[:color]="invalid"
      render "new" # Needs to be inside the "else" statement
      # Otherwise you will get a double render error
    end
  end

  def user_params
    params.require(:user)
          .allow(:username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
  end
end
```

## Added:

You can also simplify your form_for to

```
<%= form_for(:user) do |f| %>
```

Rails will by convention route the form to `UserController#create`.
Also you should use `<label>` tags for accessibility, as they help people who use assistive technology such as screen readers to find the correct inputs.

By using the built in `label` helper rails will set up the `for` attribute and you can translate the label texts with Rails built in I18n functionality.

```
<% page_title="Signup" %>
<div class="Sign_Form">
  <h1>Sign up</h1>
  <%= form_for(:user) do |f| %>
    <div class="row">
      <%= f.label :username %>:</br> 
      <%= f.text_field :username %>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <%= f.label :email %>:</br>
      <%= f.text_field :email %>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <%= f.label :password %>:</br>
      <%= f.password_field :password %>
    </div>
    <%= f.submit :Signup %>
  <% end %>
  <% if @user.errors.any? %>
    <ul class="Signup_Errors">
    <%# for loops are almost never used in ruby. %>
    <%# .each is the idiomatically correct way %>
    <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |message_error| %>
      <li>* <%= message_error %></li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
  <% end %>
</div>
```